# Problem with xtick distance

Tags: pgfplots

I'm using `pgfplots` to plot experimental data and there are currently way too many marks on the *x*-axis.

In the documentation I found the `xtick distance`-command, but LaTeX gives this error message:

> I do not know the key '/tikz/xtick distance'

What am I doing wrong?

```
% Preamble
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5, width=0.7\linewidth}

% Code
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xtick distance=10,   
    xlabel={Magnetic field [\si{G}]},
    ylabel={EPR-Signal [\si{a.u.}]},
    xmin=3390, xmax=3460,
  ]

    \addplot[black] table {...};
    \addplot[red] table {...};

    \legend{Experiment,Simulation}

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I would guess that the version of `pgfplots`  you have installed doesn't correspond to the version of the documentation you're reading, your example works fine here, with version 1.14 (the latest version). `\pgfplotsversion` will print the version number, so you can add that to your document to see which version you have.

Comment: I'm using 1.12.1 although I have installed the version 1.14... How can I force LaTeX to use the latest version?

Comment: You would need to provide more information for anyone to answer that  I think. Which TeX distribution are you using (TeX Live, MikTeX, MacTeX), and how did you install it (matters for TeX Live at least, I think), and how did you install `pgfplots` 1.14. Either way, I would recommend either completely rewriting this question, or deleting it altogether and post a new one about the installation issue.

Comment: That said, there are other ways of specifying ticks as well, e.g. `xtick={3390,3400,...,3460}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. The OP may have 1.14 installed, but they are explicitly saying `compat=1.5`....

Comment: @Rmano Yes, but the code still works (I *did* test). The compatibility setting (obviously) doesn't remove the `xtick distance` altogether. And the OP also said that `\pgfplotsversion` printed 1.12.1 ...

Comment: When writing `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14, width=0.7\linewidth}` in the preamble I should specify to use that version, unfortunately, LaTeX says > ! Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.14' unknown in choice key '/pgfplots/compat/

Comment: Oh and I have TexLive 2015

Comment: Of course, you've already told us that the version that LaTeX picks up is 1.12, a compatibility setting of 1.14 cannot work when 1.12 is the actual version used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, the problem here is that you're reading the manual for version 1.14, while the actual version you have installed LaTeX is 1.12.1, in which the `xtick distance` key was not implemented. Instead you can use `xtick={3390,3400,...,3460}` to specify the tick locations.

You will most likely get the correct manual version if you do `texdoc pgfplots` from a terminal/command prompt, if not you can get it at https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgfplots/files/pgfplots/1.12.1/.

Seems you have tried installing version 1.14 somehow. If you need help with your installation issues, please ask a new question about that, with more details about your system. You could consider simply upgrading to TeX Live 2016 (see [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) if you're on some Ubuntu-like distro).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12, width=0.7\linewidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xtick={3390,3400,...,3460},
    xlabel={Magnetic field [\si{G}]},
    ylabel={EPR-Signal [\si{a.u.}]},
    xmin=3390, xmax=3460,
    ]    
    \addplot coordinates {(3400,0)(3450,0)};
    \legend{Experiment}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```